# Drupal form design without using associative arrays

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms, drupal-fields

How to design Drupal forms without coding a lot?

Comment: Hey Dinesh, it's a little bit unclear what you are asking. Maybe you can update your question and share some code. Anyways, **Drupal 6 is end-of-live since February 2016**. https://www.drupal.org/forum/general/news-and-announcements/2015-11-09/drupal-6-end-of-life-announcement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has a really nice Webform module so if you want to avoid programming you can install and use it:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/6.x-3.23

Check out for i.e. Youtube tutorials about this module. It is well documented.

But if you want to go with codding solution it's up to your codding style and code organization.